# Preciso chamar uma activity através de um fragment, procurei algumas respostas mas não deram certo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-adapter, fragment

JAVA

public class ContatoFragment extends Fragment {

```
Button btnMaps;
TextView txtMaps;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contato, container, false);}

    public void onViewCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
       txtMaps= (TextView) txtMaps.findViewById(R.id.txtMaps);

       txtMaps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

           }
       });
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta trocar o trecho

`Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);`

para

`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);`